# How does MS Entity Framework map from the conceptual model to CLR types?

Tags: entity-framework-4, poco

Given an Entity Data Model (EDMX) with "Code Generation Strategy" set to "None", how does EF determine which CLR types to map the conceptual model to?

I think I read somewhere that it just probes the assembly for types that match the conceptual model, but that was in reference to a CTP edition of EF. Is this still the case?
Can I control this process somehow?

In particular, I am in a scenario where I am moving a substantial codebase from using Linq2SQL to using POCO with EF 4.0. Thus, I have the Linq2SQL classes as well as my POCO classes, for now residing in the same assembly, but in different namespaces. I'm trying to have a smooth migration from L2S to EF so I would like to have the two frameworks run in parallel for a while. However, I get a runtime-error saying

> The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is
>   ambiguous because multiple CLR types 
>   match the EDM type 'SomeType'.
>   Previously found CLR type 
>   'SomeNamespace.SomeType', newly found
>   CLR type 'SomeNamespace.POCO.SomeType'

where SomeNamespace is the namespace of the L2S entities. This error makes sense if EF is just probing for all types matching the conceptual model. Can I confine EF to only probe the SomeNamespace.POCO namespace? Or should I put my POCO objects in another assembly? Or should I take a third approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice this comment from the ADO.NET team blog:

> Jeff 25 Feb 2010 9:10 AM @Derek
>
> This is intentional. You can put your
>   POCO classes in whatever namespace
>   you'd like. The Entity Framework's by
>   convention mechanism for detecting
>   which properties on the entity match
>   the properties of entities in your
>   model does not use Namespace. What
>   matters is that the type name (without
>   namespace) matches the EntityType name
>   in your model (edmx/csdl file).
>
> One area to watch out for is if you
>   have multiple types with the same name
>   but in different namespaces. Because
>   we don't account for namespace, we
>   detect that we've found multiple types
>   and we throw an exception.
>
> Jeff

See this article:
[link text](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/02/18/entity-framework-poco-template-updated-for-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate.aspx)