# Entity Framework Code First and Database First Bug/Conflict

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, code-first, ef-code-first

I have two projects in a VS 2010 solution: Data and DataForm. In my Data project I have both a Code first and Database first version of the same data model (e.g. DataPoco and DataDb). These classes have the same exact entity names within them, etc...  These two versions are each in their own namespace: DataDb is in Data and DataPoco is in Data.Poco.

In my DataForm project I have the following code:

```
DataPoco context = new DataPoco(); //Data.Poco.DataPoco
foreach(var u in context.Urls)     //Data.Poco.Url
{
    //do stuff with u.
}
```

I get the following error when `context.Urls` is enumerated (and loaded due to lazy-loading):

> Could not find the conceptual model type for 'Data.Url'.

Why am I getting an error about an entity in the **OTHER** version (e.g. how can I get an error about Data.Url when I'm enumerating Data.Poco.Url)?  Is there something about code first that is making it pick up the Database first entity classes in another namespace but in the same project?  Is this a bug in Code First or my fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework does not use the namespace as part of the name - entity names themselves must be unique.

Comment: Wow - mind blown!  Well, after your answer I searched some more since I had a better idea what to look for and found this other Q/A - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521497/how-does-ms-entity-framework-map-from-the-conceptual-model-to-clr-types .  Thanks for your help!